# Reading values from variables

Tags: variable

I am trying to read values from variables like this

```
server=$(cat "$CONF_PATH" | grep "DevServer" | cut -d'=' -f2)
echo "server is : $server "
port=$(cat "$CONF_PATH" | grep "DevPort" | cut -d'=' -f2)
echo "port is : $port "
dbname=$(cat "$CONF_PATH" | grep "DevDatabase" | cut -d'=' -f2)
echo "dbname is :   $dbname "
echo jdbc:sqlserver://$server:$port;database=$dbname;
```

The last echo statement is not working, I am expecting output like

```
jdbc:sqlserver://abc:1433;database=devdb;
```

where `abc` is server name, `1433` is port and `devdb` is dbname.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `$CONF_PATH` in your question, and show us not only what you want but what the current output actually is. Don't make us guess

Comment: I would _guess_ the main problem is you're not quoting all your strings

Comment: Given this is stuff with jdbc you're probably trying to parse XML, and there are much better tools for that than the ones you're using here

Comment: @fuzzydrawings because there is no need to process the config files path in the script. It is the configs contents that matter

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot the quotes.

I've substituted the variables content, as the real input is unknown.

Without quotes:

```
[user@machine test]$ server=asdf
echo "server is : $server "
port=asdf2
echo "port is : $port "
dbname=asdf3
echo "dbname is :   $dbname "
echo jdbc:sqlserver://$server:$port;database=$dbname;
server is : asdf 
port is : asdf2 
dbname is :   asdf3 
jdbc:sqlserver://asdf:asdf2
[user@machine test]$
```

With the unescaped semicolon `;` you are telling the shell that a new command begins.
As you can see the shell is assigning `$dbname` to `$database`:

```
[user@machine test]$ echo $database
asdf3
```

With quotes:

```
[user@machine test]$ #!/bin/bash
server=asdf
echo "server is : $server "
port=asdf2
echo "port is : $port "
dbname=asdf3
echo "dbname is :   $dbname "
echo "jdbc:sqlserver://$server:$port;database=$dbname;"
server is : asdf 
port is : asdf2 
dbname is :   asdf3 
jdbc:sqlserver://asdf:asdf2;database=asdf3;
[user@machine test]$
```

Comment: i added the quotes and still not working the output now is    ;database=devdb for the last echo statement

Comment: I've added the full output. On my bash shell the script is providing the output specified by you.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, any explanation?

Comment: @mashuptwice Downvote removed after explanation added.